# Elasticsearch: Term search not working on special characters

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, analyzer, mappings

I am using Elasticsearch latest version 5.6.4. I want to index the special characters and search them for the field **title.special**. Below is my mappings:

```
PUT index1
    {
    "mappings": {
          "isContainer:false": {
            "properties": {
              "connectorSpecific": {
                "properties": {

              "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "store": true,
                "fields": {
                  "special":{
                     "type": "text",
                     "analyzer": "special",
                     "search_analyzer": "special"
                }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "settings": {
          "index": {
            "analysis": {
              "analyzer": {

                  "special": {
                  "filter": [
                    "lowercase"
                  ],
                  "tokenizer": "whitespace"
                }
              }

            }
            }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

When I query in Kibana using term query,

```
GET index1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "title.special": {
        "value": "-unconstrained_net_use_inf_tw"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Nothing returns. But when I do a match search, documents do return. for eg.

```
GET index1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title.special": {
        "value": "-unconstrained_net_use_inf_tw"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there something wrong in my mappings? How to make term query work on special characters like *,-,+ etc. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the term query works with the keyword datatype. title.special is a text datatype.to make term query work you have to change your title.special mapping 
Take a look here, the section called Why doesn’t the term query match my document?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html